# How to encode a dictionary then write it to a file then decode it to then set it as variables?

Tags: python, json, variables, encoding

So, I am creating a game where there are some variables like: Have they got x paper, have they done this room, what they have in their inventory. As seen here:
[Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98aZu.png)
And then lets say I then restart the game, it checks if there is any data in the file, if not it creates the variables (this isn't important) but if so it will load them as seen here:
[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if9di.png)
And this is what the json file looks like:

```
{"hd1": true, "hd2": true, "hd3": false, "hd4": false, "hd5": false, "P1": "Unlocked", "P2": "Unlocked", "P3": "Unlocked", "P4": "Locked", "P5": "Locked", "Inv": ["Killed my wife, my name is John. \n John created the safe // The code to the SAFE is 728 and the code to the LOCK is 1538 // Born on the 6th of November", "If you have found this letter, good, help me, I think I have gone south to the nearby yellow tree, PLEASE HELP!! \n Suit of Sir John the Great // The sky seems blue today, I'm wearing a red coat and some cargo green trousers, the sun looks more yellow today too"]}
```

In theory, what I want to do is somehow encode this in base64, then decode it to then read it as a json to then reload the save data.

Here's a concise way of putting it:

Variables encoded --> store in file --> Reads and decodes it --> loads the variables

NOTE: I do have a list called "Inventory" as seen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind including your code with the right formatting (using single-backticks `\`` for inline code and triple-backticks `\`\`\`` for blocks of code), ideally with a minimal example?

Comment: Why do you need to encode it? Is it just for obfuscation, to make it harder for the user to read the file?

Comment: Anyway, you can use `json.dumps()` to create the JSON as a string. Then encode that in base64 and write that to the file. You reverse the process when you're reloading the data.

Comment: Yes it is so that it is harder to change it, im thinking of like encoding it a couple times (which I know how to do) just how am i going to actually read it as a json to then reload the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `base64` library along with the string variants of `json.dump` and `json.load`.

```
import base64, json

def save():
    dictionary = { ... }
    with open("save.dat", "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(base64.b64encode(json.dumps(dictionary).encode()))
```

When you reload it you use:

```
with open("save.dat", "rb") as infile:
    dictionary = json.loads(base64.b64decode(infile.read()))
```

Comment: That is smart but how would I do the part where it actually grabs the variables from the dictionary and sets it as the variables in the current python file as in the photo it shows it doing|

variable in code = loaded_json_stuff ["whatever the thing is called"]

Comment: That part doesn't change. the only difference is how you read from the file.

Comment: I'm getting the error:
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\Scripts\Game\Game.py", line 365, in <module>
    save()
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\Scripts\Game\Game.py", line 86, in save
    outfile.write(base64.b64encode(json.dumps(dictionary)))
                  
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
'''

Comment: Call `.encode()` to convert the JSON to a byte string.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean, where should I call it?

Comment: Look at the edited answer, I put it in there.

Comment: Ive done it but still doesnt work: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Do I have to encode it as something?

Comment: I've changed the file mode to be binary.